# Google maps API JS3 SSL

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a website here : www.hosting6280514.az.pl/ that uses SSL ... I try to display google maps on that page, but only the controls, markers and map/satellite switch is displayed, the actual map isn't. This is the code I'm using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function refreshing() {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",5000);
}








function initialize()
{
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo$lat; ?>,<?php echo$lgt; ?>);
    var mapOptions = 
    {
    zoom: 18,
    center: position,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

/*var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://hosting6280514.az.pl/pawel/images/car.png',
    // This marker is 129 pixels wide by 42 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(129, 42),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,42.
    new google.maps.Point(18, 42)
);*/



var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: position,                         // its position is where position variable points
        title: "Car's position"
        //icon: image
    });

marker.setMap(map);                                 // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:refreshing();">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, Question is: does anyone know why map is not displaying ?

Comment: Why do you have the `setTimeout` on page load?

Comment: because the map is refreshing every 5 secs to update the new position of the marker. Is there any alternative to that without using AJAX ?

Comment: You aren't using AJAX now.  Do you think you are? Why wouldn't you want to (reloading the whole page and reinitializing the map is a lot more expensive in data and API loads than just updating the marker position with AJAX)?

Comment: no I am not using AJAX now, plain JS. I said I don't want to use AJAX, simply because I have no experience whatsoever with AJAX. But I doubt this is the problem of map not loading. Before I implemented https on the website, maps were loading normally.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the position on the map, try something along those lines. 
You may also use [`geolocation.watchPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition) if you would like to get the current position.

```
var position, marker;

function updateLocation() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/something.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            marker.setPosition(position);
        }
    });
}



function initialize() {
    position = // same as you have it

    // ...

    marker = // same as you have it
}
```